# PHP stop the session from ending / logging the user out

Tags: php

I am wanting to keep the session/user logged in for at least 3600000 seconds, 
I have tried multiple ways of PHP and still after looking at highly voted answers...it still wont work and logs the user out after labout 5-10 minutes.

**PHP**

```
<?php
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600000);
session_start();


if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){
header("Location: admin-login.php");
exit(); }

if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && (time() - $_SESSION['username'] > 3600000)) {
    session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
    session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
}
$_SESSION['username'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp
```

Comment: Have you set `session.cookie_lifetime` to a higher than default value?

Comment: yes, I added that and still logs out after 5-10 minutes @ArSeN

Comment: I would avoid doing that all together as each session uses up memory, that is partially why the default is set to 5-10 mins. If you don't kill those sessions you will run out of memory on your server after a while.

Comment: @ATechGuy - so whats the method to prevent such a short session time

Comment: Did you figure out whether your code actually times out the session too soon (e.g. the session_destroy() is called) or something else happens?

Comment: @ArSeN , I changed the session save path, and changed the timeout after creating a php.ini file... now works a charm

Answer (score 0):

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 60 * 60 * 24 * 7);
```

Use that instead of session.gc_maxlifetime

Comment: If anything additionally and not instead, both are relevant for different cases.